# Receive events on CCScene class using cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create a class that handles all the touch events in a particular scene.

So i have the main scene class (HelloWorldScene) and another class (TouchEventHandling) that is suposed to handle the touch events. I also instantiate the TouchEventHandling class on HelloWorldClass, the problem is that i never receive the touch events on the EventHandlingClass.

My approach is correct ? I mean, is it possible to handle touch event in a CCScene class instantiated on other CCScene class ?

Here is TouchEventHandling.m

```
-(id) init
 {
    self = [super init];
    if(!self) return nil;

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return self;
  }

  + (TouchEventHandling *)scene
  {
       return [[self alloc] init];
  }

  -(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
       CCLOG(@"Touch Begin");
  }
```

Comment: Why you need the Separate TouchEventHandling Class?

Comment: Because its easier to reuse code

Answer (score 0):

In your `init` methode replace `self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` to `self.touchEnabled = YES;` and add Touchdelegate `<CCTouchAllAtOnceDelegate>` in your .h file.

use following mehode

```
- (void)registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:
           self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have no self.touchEnabled property, and have no <CCTouchAtOnceDelegate> protocol. My class inherit from CCScene and i'm using cocos2d v3.0

Comment: In Cocos 2d V3.0 for setting Touch Delegate you need to set up self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;